# Leaving a while loop to execute next command in BASH script in a linux environment

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, do-while

I hope you are all doing well! I am trying to poll a directory once every so often until data is done entering the directory, and when it finishes I want to execute my next task on the directory using a bash script in a linux environment. I do not have access to inotify-tools. The way I am testing this process is by typing the following into one shell command line:

```
while true; do touch /home/tmp/fun_temp/nothing.txt; sleep 10; rm -rf /home/tmp/fun_temp/nothing.txt; done
```

This creates a file in a temp directory called nothing.txt and then sleeps 10 seconds and then removes it, then does it again until I tell it to stop. My bash script watches the directory at intervals of 20 seconds and then at 20 seconds writes the directory info into a file called old_stat.txt. Then after another 20 seconds it compares a new_stat with the old stat, and if they are equal it should exit the loop and do the next part of the command, and if they are not equal to keep polling. Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR_TO_CHECK='/home/tmp/fun_temp/'
OLD_STAT_FILE='/home/sleep_files/old_stat.txt'

if [ -e $OLD_STAT_FILE ]; then
    OLD_STAT=`cat $OLD_STAT_FILE`
else
    OLD_STAT="nothing"
fi

NEW_STAT=`stat -t $DIR_TO_CHECK`

while true; do
    if [ "$OLD_STAT" != "$NEW_STAT" ]; then
        echo 'Directory is still updating.'
        sleep 20
        echo $NEW_STAT > $OLD_STAT_FILE
        echo 'Checking again.'
    elif [ "$OLD_STAT" == "$NEW_STAT" ]; then
        echo 'Directory is done updating. Move on.'
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

I am using exit 0 as a check at the moment. I test the bash script by running the while loop above in the command line and then in another shell I run this bash script, then I give it about a minute to make sure the directory has changed, then I kill the while loop in the command line and let the bash script run another minute but it never changes to the second condition and leaves the loop unless I kill the script and run it again. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Your loop is changing the directory `/home/myhome/tmp`, the script is checking `/home/tmp/fun_tmp`.

Comment: @Barmar this was an oversight on my part when writing this, it is correct in my script.

Comment: The best way to debug shell scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning. It will then show each command as it's executed, with the variables expanded.

Comment: @d_kennetz: edit your question to fix the difference in directory names (as pointed out by Barmar)

Comment: @d_kennetz: nowhere in your `while` loop do you ever (re)set your `OLD_STAT` or `NEW_STAT` variables so your tests will always generate the same results every time through the loop

Comment: @Barmar I will give that a try, thanks.

Comment: @markp I fixed the question, and do I reset them in the conditional?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could build a [mcve] that actually reproduces the problem. Note in this context that "Verifiable" means that someone (who isn't you) should be able to run it, without needing to have a `/home/sleep_files` or such, and get the same result.

Comment: ...right now, the question isn't asked in a way that makes it clear what your problem actually is. You're describing what your code *does*, but if you're explicitly calling out how that differs from what it *should do*, you aren't doing so very clearly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it is verifiable, and I told you how to run it in the description. You do not need any pre-existing file to make this work, sleep_file is an output directory that the bash script writes old_stat.txt to. I think that is fairly clear in the code.

Comment: @d_kennetz re: when to (re)set your variables ... *shrug* ... probably after the `sleep 20` to see if the status has changed

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okay, maybe it is less clear than I thought. Is the code difficult to follow? I can edit the whole explanation to make it shorter but I think at this point it might be lost to the interverse.

Comment: @markp haha thanks mark. I will give it a go.

Comment: @d_kennetz, what the code *does* is easy to follow. What the code is *intended to do*, and how the two differ, not so much. And the point of a MCVE is so someone can reproduce your problem and then test their answer by applying the change they're suggesting -- which is to say that code shouldn't just be readable but *testable*.

Comment: BTW -- `==` isn't guaranteed to work in `[ ]`; the POSIX-specified comparison operator is `=`. That could cause you some pain if this script were run with `dash`. There are also some quoting issues that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: If `sleep_file` should be a newly created temp directory, use `mktemp -d` (within the script) to create it under the user's `TMPDIR`. Then they don't need to edit your script to substitute a location they can actually write to. `/home/tmp` and `/home/sleep_files` are certainly not locations that will work for anyone but you.

Comment: Similarly, if you expect the given while loop to be running in the background, why not kick it off in the background in your primary script?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understand what you are saying now. You would have to create a directory in order to reproduce the code, which I should've just included in the code itself. I will fix that. I will also check out the spellcheck.net, thanks for the tip. I am teaching myself bash because it seems useful, so I am not very good at this yet. You have taught me a lot, also that set -x option has done wonders for me already.

Comment: It also doesn't hurt to have a `echo "THIS SHOULD BE REACHED BUT IS NOT"` or a `echo "THIS SHOULD NEVER BE REACHED"` somewhere in your code -- makes it more clear what your expected behavior is and how your actual behavior differs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this variant of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR_TO_CHECK='/home/tmp/fun_temp/'
OLD_STAT="initial"

while true; do
    NEW_STAT=`stat -t $DIR_TO_CHECK`
    if [ "$OLD_STAT" != "$NEW_STAT" ]; then
        echo 'Directory is still updating.'
        sleep 20
        OLD_STAT=$NEW_STAT
        echo 'Checking again.'
    elif [ "$OLD_STAT" == "$NEW_STAT" ]; then
        echo 'Directory is done updating. Move on.'
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

Comment: worked, like a charm, thanks cryo. I just tried what you suggested with OLD_STAT=$NEW_STAT but I left the initial NEW_STAT outside of the loop and it wasn't working. I understand now! Thank you.

Comment: I glad you understand this solution. you're welcome! :)